# can't use setAttribute() for tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

I'm completely new to tailwindcss. I'm currently trying to dynamically create div and set its tailwind styles using javascript, for example, I've a code like below:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("style", "bg-slate-800");
```

the bg-slate-800 does not show up.....

My questions is: is this not supported by tailwindcss ? if so, how could I make it work ?

Thanks!

I tried:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("style", "bg-slate-800");
```

the bg-slate-800 doesn't apply. However, if I try like this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("style", "background-color:#000000");
```

it works perfectly fine.

Comment: `bg-slate-800` is not a valid CSS property. It seems it is a class.

Comment: yup I tried div.classList.add("bg-slate-800") and it works perfectly ! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work and rightfully so.

Tailwind does not apply styles in this way. It uses utility classes.

So, that means that the `bg-slate-800` you are trying to add as style should instead be added in the classList of the element for its declared styles to be applied by tailwind.

E.g.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.classList.toggle("bg-slate-800");
// or
div.classList.add("bg-slate-800");
```